# Cannot create mesh due to AttributeError: 'bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'new'

Tags: python

The following error keeps showing up in my script:

```
AttributeError: 'bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'new'
```

How do I fix this?

````
import bpy

# Set the size of the brick
brick_width = 0.5
brick_height = 0.25
brick_depth = 0.2

# Create a new mesh and object
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("Brick")
obj = bpy.data.objects.new("Brick", mesh)

# Set the location and dimensions of the object
obj.location = (0, 0, 0)
obj.dimensions = (brick_width, brick_height, brick_depth)

# Add vertices to the mesh
v1 = mesh.vertices.new((0, 0, 0))
v2 = mesh.vertices.new((brick_width, 0, 0))
v3 = mesh.vertices.new((brick_width, brick_depth, 0))
v4 = mesh.vertices.new((0, brick_depth, 0))
v5 = mesh.vertices.new((0, 0, brick_height))
v6 = mesh.vertices.new((brick_width, 0, brick_height))
v7 = mesh.vertices.new((brick_width, brick_depth, brick_height))
v8 = mesh.vertices.new((0, brick_depth, brick_height))

# Create edges and faces for the brick
mesh.edges.new((v1, v2))
mesh.edges.new((v2, v3))
mesh.edges.new((v3, v4))
mesh.edges.new((v4, v1))
mesh.edges.new((v1, v5))
mesh.edges.new((v2, v6))
mesh.edges.new((v3, v7))
mesh.edges.new((v4, v8))
mesh.edges.new((v5, v6))
mesh.edges.new((v6, v7))
mesh.edges.new((v7, v8))
mesh.edges.new((v8, v5))
mesh.faces.new((v1, v2, v3, v4))
mesh.faces.new((v5, v6, v7, v8))
mesh.faces.new((v1, v4, v8, v5))
mesh.faces.new((v2, v6, v7, v3))
mesh.faces.new((v4, v3, v7, v8))
mesh.faces.new((v1, v5, v6, v2))

# Create a new material
mat = bpy.data.materials.new("BrickMaterial")
mat.diffuse_color = (0.8, 0.4, 0.2, 1.0)

# Assign the material to the object
obj.data.materials.append(mat)

# Add the object to the scene
scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.collection.objects.link(obj)
```
````

Comment: Hello ! If you don't mind me asking, was this generated by an AI assisted tool ? If so, would you mind sharing the prompt you used to generate this ?

Answer (score 1):

As you have noticed, when you run your script, it errors out with `AttributeError: 'bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'new'`  and positions the cursor at the end of line `v1 = mesh.vertices.new((0, 0, 0))`.

[image]

So apparently there is no method or property with the name `new` on `mesh.vertices`. You can rewrite your script like this but take note the generated brick is very small so you will either need to increase the `brick_width` etc dimensions or zoom in with <kbd>Numpad . (dot)</kbd> after you have generated your object.

```
import bpy

# Set the size of the brick
brick_width = 0.5
brick_height = 0.25
brick_depth = 0.2

# Create a new mesh and object
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("Brick")
obj = bpy.data.objects.new("Brick", mesh)

# Set the location and dimensions of the object
obj.location = (0, 0, 0)
obj.dimensions = (brick_width, brick_height, brick_depth)

# Add vertices to the mesh
v1 = (0, 0, 0)
v2 = (brick_width, 0, 0)
v3 = (brick_width, brick_depth, 0)
v4 = (0, brick_depth, 0)
v5 = (0, 0, brick_height)
v6 = (brick_width, 0, brick_height)
v7 = (brick_width, brick_depth, brick_height)
v8 = (0, brick_depth, brick_height)

verts = (v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8)

faces = ((1, 5, 4, 0),
         (6, 5, 1, 2),
         (0, 3, 2, 1),
         (6, 2, 3, 7),
         (4, 7, 3, 0),
         (5, 6, 7, 4))

mesh.from_pydata(verts, [], faces)

# Create a new material
mat = bpy.data.materials.new("BrickMaterial")
mat.diffuse_color = (0.8, 0.4, 0.2, 1.0)

# Assign the material to the object
obj.data.materials.append(mat)

# Add the object to the scene
scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.collection.objects.link(obj)
```